# Get permalink from loop to use outside of loop

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In an archive page I have a list of X posts and each post has a thumbnail that is being displayed in a lightbox slideshow.

What i'm trying, is to get the permalink for each post item within a loop, and to print it in a script function that is outside of the loop.

This is the loop for the archive page.

```
<?php 
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'gallery', 'paged' => $paged, 'orderby' => 'rand' ) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="work-info">
  <a rel="<?php the_permalink();?>" href="<?php echo $imageF[0]; ?>" class="lightbox" data-title="<?php the_title();?>" ></a>
</div>


<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and on the same php file, just outside the loop...

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.lightbox').iLightBox(

  {
    skin: 'smooth',
    path: 'horizontal',
    linkId: 'showcase',

social: {
  buttons: {
    facebook: {
      URL: "<?php echo get_permalink();?>",
      text: "Share it on your Timeline"
    },
  }
},

  }
);

}); 
</script>
```

As you see, the **URL: ""**  will only display 1 random permalink from the post list, because is outside the loop.

What i want is to have a URL:" " for each of the posts with their own permalink.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After taking a look at the plugin's code, I suggest to try a different approach. This should work even for image galleries.

You can use the `data-options` attribute to set the sharing url of each `.lightbox` item.

Try this:

```
<a rel="<?php the_permalink();?>" href="<?php echo $imageF[0]; ?>" class="lightbox" data-title="<?php the_title();?>" data-options="social: { facebook: { URL: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>', text:'Share this photo on Facebook' }, twitter: { URL: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>', text:'Share this photo on Twitter' }   }" ></a>
```

And your javascript code should be:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.lightbox').iLightBox({
        skin: 'smooth',
        path: 'horizontal',
        linkId: 'showcase'
    });

}); 
</script>
```

---

As I see from your code, each `.lightbox` element has a `rel` attribute with the post permalink. So I suggest to loop through each element with the class `.lightbox` (using jQuery `.each()` method) and add the `iLightBox` function for each of them. Try the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.lightbox').each(function() {

        $(this).iLightBox({
            skin: 'smooth',
            path: 'horizontal',
            linkId: 'showcase',
            social: {
                buttons: {
                    facebook: {
                          URL: $(this).attr("rel"),
                          text: "Share it on your Timeline"
                    }
                }
             }

        });

    });

 });
```

Let me know if it works.

More info about jQuery `.each()` method [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: PERFECT! Can't thank you enough for your solution! And just when i was about to remove the whole script because it wasnt working :)

Comment: Hey andreivictor, i've just notice something. The code is running working ok, but since its wrapped in a .each() function, the grouped image lightbox doesnt work. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hey, I will take a look at the `iLightBox` documentation and come back with an answer.

Comment: It seems that their support its closed and comment section also closed :/

Comment: Hey mate, I've updated my answer... Try it and let me know it it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do with your script, but the way to go would be to build an array of permalinks as the loop runs

Before your loop begins make a

```
$permalink_array = array();
```

Then within the link for each post

```
$permalink_array[] = get_the_permalink();
```

When you want to print all your permalinks use something like

```
foreach( $permalink_array as $permalink ) {
    echo $permalink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max for your answer. I've updated my question and also i've added a link to the page.